# AlarmManager cannot work from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

gives the ALARM_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable when called from a class that extends broadcastReceiver.

I tried the following,

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService("alarm");
```

I get The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type MyReceiver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ALARM_SERVICE is a static constant inside Context. Refer to it like this:

```
Context.ALARM_SERVICE
```

Also, you need a context to call getSystemService, the onReceive() method should provide you with one.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: yes it does. but how can I use it with the getSystemService ?